# How to calculate GINI INDEX for binary classification?

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I am solving the GINI INDEX question number 4.8.2 from the below link but I am not able to understand the exact solution. Can anyone please let me know how all the four parts of that question number 4.8.2 are solved in the below link ?

http://csucidatamining.weebly.com/assign-4.html

I have tried using the same formula as mentioned in the example but somehow I am not able to understand how this is working out.

if someone has any understanding of how to calculate GINI INDEX, please let me know in brief.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wikipedia has a lot of background information. You should read [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gini_coefficient)

Formally, the Gini is almost trivial. It's the sum of squared *relative* amounts (= probabilities if one would randomly pick).

```
sum( (x/sum(x))**2 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the formula for gini index and entropy.

[image: thatascience Gini Index and Entropy Formula]

```
# giniscore calculates the score for a node using above formula
def giniscore(node):
    nodesum, percents = calcpercent(node)
    score = round(1 - sum([i**2 for i in percents.values()]), 3)
    print('Gini Score for node {} : {}'.format(node, score))
    return score
```

where node is a dictionary containing classes and their counts.

[Gini Index Vs Entropy](https://thatascience.com/learn-machine-learning/gini-entropy/)

This link explains Gini Index and Entropy and shows with an example how they are calculated.